# I enter an invalid result for a while loop it works, but after a few times the while loop keeps repeating in time_taken()

Tags: python, testing, while-loop, repeat, invalidation

```
client_dict = {"NeQua":"High","EmVol":"Moderate","RiVam":"High","EdLis":"Moderate"} 
Intensity_sports = {"High":["swimming","aerobics"],"Moderate":["Basketball","Hiking"]}
def activity_recorder(): 
    def clientID_choice(): 
        global clientid,intensity 
        clientid = input("What client would you like to edit?:") 
        while clientid not in client_dict: 
            clientid = input("\nPlease enter the correct client\nWhat client would you like to edit?:")
        intensity = client_dict[clientid] 
        print("\n"+clientid,"has a",intensity,"intensity\nThe reccomened sports are:") 
        for sports in Intensity_sports[intensity]:
            print("//",sports) 

    **def time_taken():
        global time_spent
        time = [] #The variable time is equal to an empty array
        for sport in Intensity_sports[intensity]:
            try: 
                time_spent = int(input("\nPlease select the minutes spent on "+sport+":"))
                while not 0 <= time_spent <= 120: 
                    time_spent = int(input("\nPlease select the minutes spent on "+sport+" between 0 and 120:")) 
            except:
                print("Please enter a number\nYou will be asked to re enter all your times") 
                time_taken() 
            time.append(time_spent) 
        total_time = 0 
        for time_spent in time: 
            total_time += time_spent 
        print("\n"+clientid+"'s total time spent is",total_time,"minutes")**

    def again(): 
        anotherRecord = input("\nDo you wis to enter another record? Type yes or y or no or n:") 
        while anotherRecord.lower() != "yes" and anotherRecord.lower() != "y" and anotherRecord.lower() != "no" and anotherRecord.lower() != "n":
            anotherRecord = input("Please answer again. Yes or No?") 
        if anotherRecord.lower() == "yes" or anotherRecord.lower() == "y": 
            print("You will now enter a new client record") 
            activity_recorder() 
        else: 
            print("Thank you") 
    clientID_choice()
    time_taken()
    again()
activity_recorder()
```

Can you test it to check for any errors and help me

Comment: Please fix your formatting/indentation first.

Comment: I just added 4 spaces to the entire code block to make it recognized by the formatter -- but there is still a random `**` that seems out of place and the indentation should be verified.

Comment: The random ** was to represent that this is the area I would like someone to focus on, sorry about that but, to make it clear, the time_taken function is where I would get all the times and add them up. This works until you enter a string then a number for both sports. What happens is that it displays the total score for every client in the dictionary and the loop never ends. Can you help me find a solution even if it does mean completely re doing this function. Thank you

Comment: I think it might have to do something with the order the code is in.